# Accessing deployed files from the Azure Portal

Tags: azure

I was recently given a task to edit a website developed by a different person. Being a C# developer, I have limited experience with Azure- mostly just deploying from Visual Studio. I'm confident about the programming edits but I'm not really sure how to access the files already deployed in Azure.

I was given the azure login credentials and I can access the account from the Azure portal. After hours of exploring, I still can't see a way to download/access the deployed files. I've seen tutorials on FTP access for app services but the site I'm supposed to edit is under cloud services.

Sorry if it's a noob question but any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your using a cloud service the options are a bit different to an app service. Firstly, the best place to get these files is from your version control repo where you're storing the source for your projects, this is going to be the best option as it will give you all the required files in a format ready to be opened in your IDE.

However, assuming that isn't possible then you can get the files from an existing cloud service, but it's a bit of a pain. There is no portal UI to do this, you'll need to hit the Rest API and use the [get-package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/jj154121.aspx) command to download the package to a storage account, then you can download from there. The files will be in the cspkg format that is used to upload cloud service packages.

Once you've got the files I'd recommend putting them in version control and have some process to publish, plus look at moving to app services at some point.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Is there a way to find out if the azure credentials have a version control repo associated with it? I used to use TFS with Visual Studio but I don't think that has anything to do with Azure. I'm also trying to avoid the 2nd option since I'd have to create a storage account that might incur additional costs.

Comment: Unless your using automated deployment to Azure, then your version control repo is going to be completely separate to Azure, none of the details will be stored there. You'd need to get them from whoever manages your repository. Storage accounts do incur a cost, but it is based on the amount of data stored and for how long, the cost to briefly download this file and then delete again is going to be miniscule, a couple of pence/cents